# Idea IntelliJ : Compile & Run Scala REPL in remote machine

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, intellij-idea, scala

I am developing a Scala application on my remote machine ( It doesnot support GUI ) I need to use IntelliJ IDEA to write my code . Can you suggest me the best way to write my code in local machine ( windows ) and execute the application in remote machine..

For now I do the following :

1. Write my code in IntelliJ IDEA
2. Commit my Code via SUbVersion in local machine
3. Update the svn in remote host
4. Compile the Code and execute in remote host

This method sucks..Kindly suggest me alternatives

I can access my remote machine via ssh